# Minimal F-semi-norms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

There are conflicting terminologies in the literature on this subject, so let me define an F-semi-norms on a real vector space $E$ to be a subadditive function $\rho:E\to[0,+\infty)$ such that $\rho\left(\frac{1}{n}e\right)\to 0$ and $\rho(te)\le \rho(e)$, for every $e\in E$ and $t\in [-1,1]$. It is well-known that any vector space topology is generated by a certain collection of F-semi-norms.

> Can we always select a collection of **incomparable** F-semi-norms which generates the topology of a TVS?

By "incomparable" I mean that neither $\rho\le \lambda$ nor $\rho\ge \lambda$ hold.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Ususally, the opposite property of a *directed* generating set of F-norms is convenient.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth For a collection $P$ of F-seminorms on $E$ consider the following convergence. A net $(e_i)$ converges to $0$ if for every $\rho\in P$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\lambda\in P$ with $\lambda\le \rho$ and $i_0$ such that $\lambda(e_i)<\varepsilon$, for $i\ge i_0$. I want to show that any linear topology on $E$ can be described this way.